# Matrix XMPP Set License

Tags: xmpp, signalr, xmppframework

When to set matrix xmpp license key in a chat system , on every connect or reconnect? or Application Start event of SignalR application?

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The license is hold in a static variable. Setting it once when your code loads the MatriX assembly should be enough.